# How to create stripe_id on subscription?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using the API stripe with django-allauth on my website, I want to create a `stripe_id` for new users who just subscribed, not long ago my code was working and today I got a new error that I have never encountered yet :

> stripe.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "stripe.api_key = "). You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface.

When an user subscribes OR login in for the first time there is a callback in which I create a new stripe_id, the callback is called but the error raise when I create a Customer. See **models.py** :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

def stripeCallback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    user_stripe_account, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if user_stripe_account.stripe_id is None or user_stripe_account.stripe_id == '':
        new_stripe_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=user.email) #error occurs here
        user_stripe_account.stripe_id = new_stripe_id['id']
        user_stripe_account.save()

user_logged_in.connect(stripeCallback)
user_signed_up.connect(stripeCallback)
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining stripe_id in the class Profile, yet this should be assigned outside it.
Try setting

```
 stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
```

above all the rest of the code.

This is also perfectly explained in this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wbfk16jEOk&t=79s

For example, this is a models.py that I created for a similar project:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in, user_signed_up
import stripe
# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY 

# Create your models here.

class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True,
     blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class userStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.stripe_id:
            return str(self.stripe_id)
        else:
            return self.user.username 

    def stripeCallback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        user_stripe_account, created = 
              userStripe.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        if created:
            print 'created for %s'%(user.username)
        if user_stripe_account.stripe_id is None or
            user_stripe_account.stripe_id == '':
            new_stripe_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=user.email)
            user_stripe_account.stripe_id = new_stripe_id['id']
            user_stripe_account.save()

def profileCallback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    userProfile, is_created = profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if is_created:
        userProfile.name = user.username
        userProfile.save()
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was wondering why it didn't work, I remember now that I erased the stripe_secret_key from models since I was using django-allauth, but I guess I should keep it on my settings too.